# How to align div li center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align all my lists, but if I align them to the center, only the texts go to the middle. How can I align the disc (the circle) as well?

```html
<div style="background-color:#e8eeff; margin:60px" align="center">
  <h1 style="padding-top:40px;" class="font-weight-bold">Vincent Van Gogh</h1>
  <h3><i>For my part I know nothing with any certainty, <br> but the sight of the stars makes me dream.</i></h3>
  <img src="http://worldofwonder.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Vincent-van-Gogh-Self-Portrait-1889-865x577.jpg" alt="Vincent Van Gogh" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:40px; border:10px solid white">
  <div>
    <h3>Here's a time line of Vincent Van Gogh's life : </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><b>1853</b> - March 30 - Vincent Van Gogh is born in Groot-Zundert, Netherlands</li>
      <li><b>1864</b> - 1866 Sent to boarding school in Zevenbergen</li>
      <li><b>1869</b> - July - Van Gogh is employed by the Hague gallery</li>
      <li><b>1873</b> - June - Van Gogh is transferred to London</li>
      <li><b>1875</b> - Van Gogh is transferred to Paris</li>
      <li><b>1876</b> - 1880 Van Gogh begins devoting his life to the evangelization of the poor in the town of Borinage, Belgium</li>
      <li><b>1880</b> - 1884 Van Gogh relocates to Brussels and begins learning the skills needed to become an artist</li>
      <li><b>1885</b> - April - Completion of The Potato Eaters</li>
      <li><b>1886</b> - March - Van Gogh moves to Paris. Discovers Impressionists and Post Impressionists</li>
      <li><b>1887</b> - Summer - Completion of Self Portrait with Straw Hat</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - February - Van Gogh moves to Arles to create a school of art</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - Van Gogh paints the famous sunflower pieces and begins suffering from mental problems</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - September - Completion of Starry Night Over the Rhone</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - September - Completion of The Café Terrace on the Place du Forum, Arles, at Night</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - October - Completion of Vincent's Bedroom in Arles</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - December - Van Gogh cuts off a portion of his ear and commits himself to a mental asylum in Saint Rémy</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - December - Ends his friendship with Gauguin</li>
      <li><b>1889</b> - May - Completion of Irises</li>
      <li><b>1889</b> - June - Completion of Starry Night</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - February - Completion of Almond Blossom</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - May - Van Gogh leaves Saint Rémy and begins contacting his brother Theo</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - May - Leaves the asylum to begin care in Auvers-sur-Oise under Dr. Paul Gachet, who was recommended by Camille Pissarro</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - July 29 - Vincent Van Gogh dies of a self-inflicted gunshot. He was buried on July 30 at Auvers-sur-Oise</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br>
  <q class="lead">I often think that the night is more alive and more richly colored than the day.</q>
  <br><br>
  <p style="font-size:25px">Read more about Vincent Van Gogh on <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh" target="_blank">his Wikipedia entry.</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: [How to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site.

Comment: Try `margin: 0 auto;  width: 200px;` to the ul .and text-align:left to li

Comment: @XYZ Thank you it works!

Comment: or you can also use 
ul li {
    list-style-position: inside;
}

instead of width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method A)**

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

**Method B)** in this way you can change color disc.

```
ul {list-style: none;}

b {margin-left: 10px;}

li {position: relative;}

li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

b {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

li {
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#e8eeff; margin:60px" align="center">
  <h1 style="padding-top:40px;" class="font-weight-bold">Vincent Van Gogh</h1>
  <h3><i>For my part I know nothing with any certainty, <br> but the sight of the stars makes me dream.</i></h3>
  <img src="http://worldofwonder.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Vincent-van-Gogh-Self-Portrait-1889-865x577.jpg" alt="Vincent Van Gogh" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:40px; border:10px solid white">
  <div>
    <h3>Here's a time line of Vincent Van Gogh's life : </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><b>1853</b> - March 30 - Vincent Van Gogh is born in Groot-Zundert, Netherlands</li>
      <li><b>1864</b> - 1866 Sent to boarding school in Zevenbergen</li>
      <li><b>1869</b> - July - Van Gogh is employed by the Hague gallery</li>
      <li><b>1873</b> - June - Van Gogh is transferred to London</li>
      <li><b>1875</b> - Van Gogh is transferred to Paris</li>
      <li><b>1876</b> - 1880 Van Gogh begins devoting his life to the evangelization of the poor in the town of Borinage, Belgium</li>
      <li><b>1880</b> - 1884 Van Gogh relocates to Brussels and begins learning the skills needed to become an artist</li>
      <li><b>1885</b> - April - Completion of The Potato Eaters</li>
      <li><b>1886</b> - March - Van Gogh moves to Paris. Discovers Impressionists and Post Impressionists</li>
      <li><b>1887</b> - Summer - Completion of Self Portrait with Straw Hat</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - February - Van Gogh moves to Arles to create a school of art</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - Van Gogh paints the famous sunflower pieces and begins suffering from mental problems</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - September - Completion of Starry Night Over the Rhone</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - September - Completion of The Café Terrace on the Place du Forum, Arles, at Night</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - October - Completion of Vincent's Bedroom in Arles</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - December - Van Gogh cuts off a portion of his ear and commits himself to a mental asylum in Saint Rémy</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - December - Ends his friendship with Gauguin</li>
      <li><b>1889</b> - May - Completion of Irises</li>
      <li><b>1889</b> - June - Completion of Starry Night</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - February - Completion of Almond Blossom</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - May - Van Gogh leaves Saint Rémy and begins contacting his brother Theo</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - May - Leaves the asylum to begin care in Auvers-sur-Oise under Dr. Paul Gachet, who was recommended by Camille Pissarro</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - July 29 - Vincent Van Gogh dies of a self-inflicted gunshot. He was buried on July 30 at Auvers-sur-Oise</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br>
  <q class="lead">I often think that the night is more alive and more richly colored than the day.</q>
  <br><br>
  <p style="font-size:25px">Read more about Vincent Van Gogh on <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh" target="_blank">his Wikipedia entry.</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="background-color:#e8eeff; margin:60px">
  <h1 style="padding-top:40px;" class="font-weight-bold">Vincent Van Gogh</h1>
  <h3><i>For my part I know nothing with any certainty, <br> but the sight of the stars makes me dream.</i></h3>
  <img src="http://worldofwonder.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Vincent-van-Gogh-Self-Portrait-1889-865x577.jpg" alt="Vincent Van Gogh" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:40px; border:10px solid white">
  <div>
    <h3>Here's a time line of Vincent Van Gogh's life : </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><b>1853</b> - March 30 - Vincent Van Gogh is born in Groot-Zundert, Netherlands</li>
      <li><b>1864</b> - 1866 Sent to boarding school in Zevenbergen</li>
      <li><b>1869</b> - July - Van Gogh is employed by the Hague gallery</li>
      <li><b>1873</b> - June - Van Gogh is transferred to London</li>
      <li><b>1875</b> - Van Gogh is transferred to Paris</li>
      <li><b>1876</b> - 1880 Van Gogh begins devoting his life to the evangelization of the poor in the town of Borinage, Belgium</li>
      <li><b>1880</b> - 1884 Van Gogh relocates to Brussels and begins learning the skills needed to become an artist</li>
      <li><b>1885</b> - April - Completion of The Potato Eaters</li>
      <li><b>1886</b> - March - Van Gogh moves to Paris. Discovers Impressionists and Post Impressionists</li>
      <li><b>1887</b> - Summer - Completion of Self Portrait with Straw Hat</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - February - Van Gogh moves to Arles to create a school of art</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - Van Gogh paints the famous sunflower pieces and begins suffering from mental problems</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - September - Completion of Starry Night Over the Rhone</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - September - Completion of The Café Terrace on the Place du Forum, Arles, at Night</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - October - Completion of Vincent's Bedroom in Arles</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - December - Van Gogh cuts off a portion of his ear and commits himself to a mental asylum in Saint Rémy</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - December - Ends his friendship with Gauguin</li>
      <li><b>1889</b> - May - Completion of Irises</li>
      <li><b>1889</b> - June - Completion of Starry Night</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - February - Completion of Almond Blossom</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - May - Van Gogh leaves Saint Rémy and begins contacting his brother Theo</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - May - Leaves the asylum to begin care in Auvers-sur-Oise under Dr. Paul Gachet, who was recommended by Camille Pissarro</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - July 29 - Vincent Van Gogh dies of a self-inflicted gunshot. He was buried on July 30 at Auvers-sur-Oise</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br>
  <q class="lead">I often think that the night is more alive and more richly colored than the day.</q>
  <br><br>
  <p style="font-size:25px">Read more about Vincent Van Gogh on <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh" target="_blank">his Wikipedia entry.</a></p>
</div>
```

remove above the code`align=center`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `list-style-position: inside;` inside `ul`

```css
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#e8eeff; margin:60px" align="center">
  <h1 style="padding-top:40px;" class="font-weight-bold">Vincent Van Gogh</h1>
  <h3><i>For my part I know nothing with any certainty, <br> but the sight of the stars makes me dream.</i></h3>
  <img src="http://worldofwonder.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Vincent-van-Gogh-Self-Portrait-1889-865x577.jpg" alt="Vincent Van Gogh" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:40px; border:10px solid white">
  <div>
    <h3>Here's a time line of Vincent Van Gogh's life : </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><b>1853</b> - March 30 - Vincent Van Gogh is born in Groot-Zundert, Netherlands</li>
      <li><b>1864</b> - 1866 Sent to boarding school in Zevenbergen</li>
      <li><b>1869</b> - July - Van Gogh is employed by the Hague gallery</li>
      <li><b>1873</b> - June - Van Gogh is transferred to London</li>
      <li><b>1875</b> - Van Gogh is transferred to Paris</li>
      <li><b>1876</b> - 1880 Van Gogh begins devoting his life to the evangelization of the poor in the town of Borinage, Belgium</li>
      <li><b>1880</b> - 1884 Van Gogh relocates to Brussels and begins learning the skills needed to become an artist</li>
      <li><b>1885</b> - April - Completion of The Potato Eaters</li>
      <li><b>1886</b> - March - Van Gogh moves to Paris. Discovers Impressionists and Post Impressionists</li>
      <li><b>1887</b> - Summer - Completion of Self Portrait with Straw Hat</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - February - Van Gogh moves to Arles to create a school of art</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - Van Gogh paints the famous sunflower pieces and begins suffering from mental problems</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - September - Completion of Starry Night Over the Rhone</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - September - Completion of The Café Terrace on the Place du Forum, Arles, at Night</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - October - Completion of Vincent's Bedroom in Arles</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - December - Van Gogh cuts off a portion of his ear and commits himself to a mental asylum in Saint Rémy</li>
      <li><b>1888</b> - December - Ends his friendship with Gauguin</li>
      <li><b>1889</b> - May - Completion of Irises</li>
      <li><b>1889</b> - June - Completion of Starry Night</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - February - Completion of Almond Blossom</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - May - Van Gogh leaves Saint Rémy and begins contacting his brother Theo</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - May - Leaves the asylum to begin care in Auvers-sur-Oise under Dr. Paul Gachet, who was recommended by Camille Pissarro</li>
      <li><b>1890</b> - July 29 - Vincent Van Gogh dies of a self-inflicted gunshot. He was buried on July 30 at Auvers-sur-Oise</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br>
  <q class="lead">I often think that the night is more alive and more richly colored than the day.</q>
  <br><br>
  <p style="font-size:25px">Read more about Vincent Van Gogh on <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh" target="_blank">his Wikipedia entry.</a></p>
</div>
```